# React TypeError: lists.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

## TypeError: lists.map is not a function

1.I'm using React to make a TodoList. It works until you add a list,
 An error occurred when adding the delete feature when the button is 
 clicked

2.Is it a problem to use use useContext to separate lists from other files?

I'm sorry for the awkwardness of the question.
Thank you for your help in solving this problem.

- TodoList.jsx

```
    import React, { useContext} from 'react';
    import Todo from './Todo';
    import { ListContext } from './ListContext';



    const TodoList = () => {
        const [lists, setLists] = useContext(ListContext);

        return (
            <div>
                {lists.map((list, index) => {
                    return <Todo list={list.todos} key={index}/>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default TodoList;
```

- Btn.jsx

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { ListContext } from './ListContext';

const Btn = (id) => {

    const [lists, setLists] = useContext(ListContext);

    const onRemove = (id) => {
        setLists({
            lists: lists.filter(list => list.id !== id)
        });
    }

    return(
        <>
        <button onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            onRemove(id);
        }}>x</button>
        </>
    );  `enter code here`
}

export default Btn;
```

- ListContext.jsx

```
import React, {useState, createContext,} from 'react';

export const ListContext = createContext();

export const ListProvider = (props) => {

    const [lists, setLists] = useState([
        {
            todos: 'Make a TodoList',
            id: 1,
        },
    ]);

    return(
        <ListContext.Provider value={[lists, setLists]}>
            {props.children}
        </ListContext.Provider>
    );   
}
```

TypeError: lists.map is not a function
TodoList
C:/Users/user/Desktop/Work/VSC-workspace/React/todolist/src/component/TodoList.jsx:11
   8 | const [lists, setLists] = useContext(ListContext);
   9 | 
  10 | return (

> 11 |     `enter code here
>        | ^  12 |         {lists.map((list, index) => {
>     13 |             return 
>     14 |         })}

Comment: In `onRemove` it should be `setLists(lists.filter(list => list.id !== id))`

Comment: so I'm a bit new to React but when you create lists with useState your saying that lists should be an array of objects with `todos` and `id`. so when you use `setLists` and pass in the object with `{ lists: lists.filter }....` I believe that object where you are giving lists for a key should be the object that is expecting `todos` and `id` so you can't set the property lists like that. you might be able to `setLists(lists.filter(list => list.id !== id))` but also not really sure where `lists` is being fed data

Comment: create a https://codesandbox.io/s/l4w3o6my59 example of your problem.

Comment: How you are adding `Btn` component, post that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is here, you are passing only `todos` from `lists` and not `id`

```
<Todo list={list.todos} key={index}/>
```

In `Todo` component you are trying to access `list.id` which is `undefined`, because you have not passed it from `TodoList` component.

In `TodoList` component, instead of passing `list.todos` you need to pass `list` only like,

```
<Todo list={list} key={index}/>
```

Your `Todo` component should be,

```
const Todo = ({list}) => { 
   return( 
      <div className="todolist"> 
        <li>
         {list.todos}
         <Btn id={list.id}/>
        </li> 
      </div> 
   ); 
}
```

Also another problem is in `Btn` component definition,

```
const Btn = (id) => { ...
```

you need to do this,

```
const Btn = ({id}) => { ... //notice the curly braces as you did in `Todo` component
```

**Note:** Still you face any issue here

```
lists.filter(list => list.id !== id)
```

You can do this,

```
lists.filter(list => Number(list.id) !== Number(id)) //possibility that `id` props might come as `string` type
```

Comment: Thanks to your kind reply, the problem has been solved. I'm going to learn a lot. :)  @ravibagul91